# Building a dataframe from many InfluxDB result series

Tags: python, pandas, influxdb

I am using the `influxdb` Python library to get a list of series in my database.  There are about 20k series.  I am then trying to build a `Pandas` `dataframe` out of the series'.  I am rounding on 15S (I'd like to get rid of the nanoseconds, and I wonder why InfluxDB's Python library's documented `get_list_series()` call is missing in all versions I've tried, but those are other questions...); I'd like to end up with one big dataframe.

Here's the code:

```
from influxdb import DataFrameClient
.... get series list ...

temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
for series in series_list:
    df = dfclient.query('select time,temp from {} where "series" = \'{}\''.format(location, temp))[location].asfreq('15S')
    df.columns = [series]

    if temp_df.empty:
        temp_df = df
    else:
        temp_df = temp_df.join(df, how='outer')
```

This starts out fine but after a few hundred series, slows down quickly, grinding nearly to a halt.  I am sure I'm not using Pandas the right way, and I'm hoping you can tell me how to do it the right way.

For what it's worth, I'm running this on relatively powerful hardware (which is why I believe I'm doing this the wrong way.)

One more thing: the time series' for each series I pull from InfluxDB may be different than all the others, which is why I'm using `join`.  I'd like to end up with a DF with a column for each series, with the datetimes appropriately sorted in the index; join does that.

Comment: I have no deep knowledge of Pandas or how Python allocates memory, but in other languages, doing the join of the new series in-loop (`temp_df = temp_df.join(df, how='outer')` ) often leads to results like this. Can you either a) pre-allocate a large data frame *before* the loop starts, fill it with NaNs or similar, and in-loop overwrite the column contents? or b) use the loop to build a list of data frames, then after the loop build a large data frame of the right size, shape, and types and fill it using the dfs from the list?

Comment: Just looked again at the Pandas documentation - df.join() will accept a list of data frames - have you tried using the loop to build a list of data frames, then after the loop, call df.join() ?

Comment: @Jason - I did.  That also was too much for the system.  Just too much data.  I've solved the problem by just comparing the data pieces at a time.  Maybe in the future I can use your method of allocating the memory for the dataframe first.  It will be a trade-off though, because I have to find the longest time series before allocating memory, which will require iterating through all the thousands of series'.  Thanks for the information and help.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me informed. Interesting problem. Good luck!